# React Native why given cors error in actions when i use django rest framework api on localhost

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework, axios, localhost, http-status-code-400

I am using react native app with api. API coded by django rest framework. I run api in localhost:8000. When i try connect to api with axios i get cors proplem. I added django-cors-header but also it didnt work. Can someone solve it? Thanks.

Frontend/actions.js

```
export const loginUser = (username, password)=>dispatch=> {
const body =JSON.stringify({ username, password })
// headers
const config ={
    headers:{
        'Accept': 'text/html',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
    }
}
const root =API()

    console.log(body);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login/", body, config)
        .then(res =>{
            dispatch({
                type:$AT.LOGIN_USER,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
```

Login.js

```
const onLoginPressed =() =>{
    const usernameError = nameValidator(username.username);
    const passwordError = passwordValidator(password.password);

    if (usernameError || passwordError) {
        setUsername({ ...username, error: usernameError });
        setPassword({ ...password, error: passwordError });
    }
    else{
        // console.log("GIRIS YAPILIYOR");
        dispatch(loginUser(username.username, password.password));
    }

}
```

API/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# my apps
'account',
# third party app
'corsheaders',
'knox',
'rest_framework',
'drf_yasg',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
 ....
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 ....
]
```

I give this error on chorme:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KvNS.png)

On Network:
[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy6Yo.png)

Comment: Try adding CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST += [ "http://localhost:8000" ]

Comment: i tried it but not works

Comment: Can you post error response from this 400 error?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a CORS error because the server is emitted a `400 Bad Request` before it gets as far as adding the CORS headers.

It isn't clear *why* it is spitting out Bad Request because you haven't provided any debugging information about that, but it seems likely it has something to do with you claiming `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` when the body is JSON and not form encoded data.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to work with axios please configure with IP address you can check ifconfig and run django python manager.py runserver ip: 8000